# Manjaro: how to update Android Studio (with snap) to bumblebee version?

Tags: manjaro, android, snap

I have the Archtic Fox version. All my straight friends have the bumblebee version. I want the bumblebee version too. HELP.

I think I used snap. I tried "snap refresh" but nothing happened. I tried settings -> update. Nothing happened. HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/android-studio/

bumblebee is simply the latest stable release. android-studio-2021.1.1.20

it's only become available as a stable release, very recently; https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/01/android-studio-bumblebee-202111-stable.html

Also, it would be a good idea to learn how to use your distribution / package manager, as you do not need to be using snaps to install Android-Studio on Manjaro / an Arch-based distros...

Android-Studio has been available in the AUR for years and is well-maintained. You would already be running Bumblebee if you were using the standard packages. (like your friends probably are).

there is also an Archwiki entry on the subject; https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Android#Android_Studio

Comment: android-studio is not a package under Arch Linux as far as I can see (at least sudo pacman -S android-studio doesn't work). And shouldn't snap have the newest edition of Android-Studio?

Comment: it's available in the AUR, as i linked you to already and as Arch's official documentation points to and suggests using, if you plan to use Android-Studio... and obviously, pacman doesn't work - you need to use a AUR helper like Yay to access the AUR... and no, the snap for Android-Studio isn't up-to-date. it's still a 2020 Arctic fox build.

Comment: Thank you so much! 'yay -S android-studio'